# Can't traverse directory tree in python with os.walk() because it says a name is not defined

Tags: python, operating-system, filesystems, directory-traversal

So as part of a homework, I have to traverse through a directory tree, and it seems that os.walk is the best choice for this. I am using cygwin to run my python scripts. The path of the tree that I am trying to traverse is:
 /cygdrive/c/Users/Kamal/Documents/School/Spring2015/CS410/htmlfiles

So in my code, here is the snippet to the os.walk() call:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk('/cygdrive/c/Users/Kamal/Documents/School/Spring2015/CS410/htmlfiles'):
```

However, when I execute the script, it gives me the following error:

```
$ python testparser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testparser.py", line 1, in <module>
    Spring2015/CS410/htmlfiles/testparser.py
NameError: name 'Spring2015' is not defined
```

I'm confused as to why it thinks 'Spring2015' is undefined? The directory clearly exists at the given path on my computer

EDIT: here is the entire code since some have asked:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import shutil

cnt = 0

print "starting..."
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk('/cygdrive/c/Users/Kamal/Documents/School/Spring2015/CS410/htmlfiles'):
for f in fileList:
    #print the path
    print "Processing " + os.path.abspath(f) + "...\n"

    #open the HTML file
    html = open(f)
    soup  = BeautifulSoup(html)

    #Filter out unwanted stuff
    [s.extract() for s in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]',  'head', 'title'])]
    visible_text = soup.getText()
    visible_text_encoded = visible_text.encode('utf-8')
    visible_text_split = visible_text_encoded.split('\n')
    visible_text_filtered = filter(lambda l: l != '', visible_text_split)

    #Generate the name of the output text file
    outfile_name = 'chaya2_' + str(cnt) + '.txt'

    #Open the output file to write in
    outfile = open(outfile_name, "w")

    #Get the URL of the html file using its Path, write it to the first line
    outfile.write(os.path.relpath(f, '/cygdrive/c/Users/Kamal/Documents/School/') + ' \n')

    #Write the visible text to the 
    for l in visible_text_filtered:
        outfile.write(l+'\n')

    #Done writing, move the output file to the appropriate directory
    shutil.move(os.path.abspath(outfile_name), '/cygdrive/c/Users/Kamal/Documents/School/Spring2015/CS410/txtFiles')

    #Rename the html file 
    html_name = 'chaya2_' + str(cnt) + '.html'
    os.rename(f, html_name)

    #Move the html file to the appropriate directory
    shutil.move(os.path.abspath(html_name), '/cygdrive/c/Users/Kamal/Documents/School/Spring2015/CS410/htmlFilesAfter')

    print html_name  + " converted to " + outfile_name + "\n"

    outfile.close()
    html.close()

    cnt+=1
```

Comment: What is line 1 of your file?

Comment: `NameError` means Python is trying to resolve Spring2015 as a variable name. I think you need to post more of the code. Preferably the entire file.

Comment: I added the entire file. Why does python think Spring2015 is a variable name though? I'm guessing I made some syntax error that I don't know about?

Comment: Is the file you've shown us `testparser.py`? Python seems to think that file starts with the text `Spring2015/CS410/htmlfiles/testparser.py`, which is not valid Python.